# Check if record exists in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to check if the entry with the id 2 exists in the settings table and if not i want that the user gets redirected to the setting_new_path. My code looks like this:

```
 def index
if Setting.find(2).present?
@patients = Patient.all
@patients_drucken = Patient.drucken

@anrede = Setting.find(1).anrede

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @patients }
end
else
  redirect_to new_setting_path
end
end
```

But somehow i get the error:

```
Couldn't find Setting with id=2
```

I dont get why this is displayed as an error! I mean in the case its not defined i worte , redirect to new_setting_path! What made i wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F) to check for record presence:

```
if Setting.exists?(2)
```

Comment: Thanks helped me a lot! And shortest answer!

Comment: The 'exists?' method is the best solution.  An alternative form (useful in similar but different circumstances) is the 'find_by' method which either returns the first matched record or nil. Usage: Model.find_by(id: 2) # => returns first matching record or nil

Answer (score 1):

`#find` will throws an exception if the record is not found.

You should use `#where` and `#any?` instead :

```
if Setting.where( id: 2 ).any?
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you don't have any record with id = 2 in Settings table. Just check it once.